# get array of arrays looping through HTML table

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have this bunch of code

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.workRow')
var codes = []
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    var timeCodesInputs = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('xCell')
    for(var j=0;j<timeCodesInputs.length;j++){
        if(timeCodesInputs[j].innerHTML == "x"){
            codes.push(timeCodesInputs[j].dataset.dataHour)
        }
    }
}
```

it works ok but it pushed everything to one array. What I want to get an array of arrays where one array if the data from one row. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, try to push row data in one array and then push this array into `codes` array like:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.workRow')
  var codes = []
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      var rowArray = [];
      var timeCodesInputs =  rows[i].getElementsByClassName('xCell')
      for (var j=0;j<timeCodesInputs.length;j++){
         if(timeCodesInputs[j].innerHTML == "x"){
            rowArray.push(timeCodesInputs[j].dataset.dataHour)
         }
      }
      codes.push(rowArray)
   }
```

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I am sorry, my answer was almost same. I didn't see yours earlier.

Comment: No problem. I know that you didn't copy.